# Random Musical Symbols in .js

Tags: javascript, random, character

I already have a (pseudo)random script that generates letters and numbers, but how do I add musical symbols into the `var characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 ";` line? Or any other Unicode character for that matter? Even if it is possible, would it display in all browsers? Most? Few?

Comment: Just put them inside the string. Have you tried like that?

Comment: [Musical Symbols (Unicode block)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_Symbols_(Unicode_block))

Comment: It only picks them as individual characters. So U+1D12x is seen as individual characters U + 1 D 1 2 x.

Comment: Looks like  \u1D11E (for example) solves the problem of that line accepting it as a character, but it appears browsers won't display the choice very well. Most attempts in Edge and IE, etc, chose something else to display other than the musical Clef. Hmmm, how to get consistent results that display what the Unicode is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of picking random symbols and should work for any Unicode char.

```js
const test = Array.from("♩♪♫♬");
const elSymbols = document.getElementById("symbols");

function createRandomSymbols() {
  let ret = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    ret += test[
      Math.trunc(Math.random() * test.length)
    ];
  }
  elSymbols.innerText = ret;
}

createRandomSymbols();
document.getElementById("again").onclick = createRandomSymbols;
```

```html
<div id="symbols" style="font-size: 30pt;margin-bottom:20px">
</div>

<button id="again">Again</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Keith, but I need it to run in mine. How did you even get ♩♪♫♬ to appear? Array allowed it? Looks like my browsers can't display it in any case. Well, like I said, I need it to run in the var characters = line.

Comment: @Ken sorry, no idea what your asking.  The simple demo here demonstrates how you pick random chars from a full Unicode based string.  `but I need it to run in mine` then make it run in yours.  I can't because you haven't even shown your code.

Comment: /* Variables */
 // UI
 var input = $("#evolutionInput");
 var characterCount = $("#numberOfCharacters");
 var exportBtn = $("#exportBtn");
 var importBtn = $("#importBtn");
 var startBtn = $("#startBtn");

 // Settings
 var characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 ";
 var delay = 30;
 var export_filename = 'EvolutionExport.txt';

 // Don't touch at that
 var btn_started = false;
 var interval_id;

I need whatever solution to run in my script.

Comment: Looks like I figured out how to have the script display a Unicode character in the var characters = line by using \u1D11E (for example), but the characters displayed do not match the Unicode character chosen each time. Browser choice?